# Tidal forces lock satellite's rotation with its planet; why not the planet's rotation with its star?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy

My astronomy course said that our moon always faces the Earth with the same side is due to the tidal forces between the two, and that this is a common thing for satellites to do in general.

OTOH, planets generally don't generally get locked into showing the same side to the star that their orbit.

Why the difference? I feel it has something to do with the scales involved, but I can't find a reasonable explanation.

Comment: Or maybe it has to do with the forces that are around when planets form (from all the unsettled gas dust) that are not around later, when the satellites stabilize around their planet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strength of the effect depends on the non-uniformity of the field, so it increases when distances are small. And is not Mercury locked (edit: in a 2:3 ratio)?

Comment: I don't think Mercury is locked—see here: https://astrosociety.org/edu/publications/tnl/22/22.html.

That said, maybe the answer is in the numbers. Maybe the strength of the Sun's pull on the planets doesn't compare to the strength of the Earth's pull on the Moon.

But if that is a general state of affairs, it is still intriguing.

Comment: @MihaiDanila Ah, now it is known that it is rotating, not really locked, but locked in a 2:3 resonance. Which indicates that tidal effects are important so close to the Sun.

Comment: It seems you were right in that it has to do with the distance between the objects relative to the size of the smaller object.

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/tide.html#mstid

"Even though the Sun is 391 times as far away from the Earth as the Moon, its force on the Earth is about 175 times as large. Yet its tidal effect is smaller than that of the Moon because tides are caused by the difference in gravity field across the Earth. The Earth's diameter is such a small fraction of the Sun-Earth distance that the gravity field changes by only a factor of 1.00017 across the Earth."

Comment: But shouldn't it also depend on the absolute strength of the respective gravitational field? The gradient alone cannot be it.

Comment: @Mihail Danila - If your numbers are correct, it follows that the ratio of gradients of the gravitational forces (on the center of earth) of the sun and and the moon are $$\frac {dF_S/dr}{dF_M/dr}= (F_S/F_M)(r_M/r_S)=175/371=0.47$$. This means that the tidal effect of the sun is only about half as strong as the tidal effect of the moon.